# Getting rid of the white space below the footer in the twenty sixteen theme in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am making my first steps learning to code. I made some courses on Internet and now I decided to continue learning from the experience while I build a Wordpress child theme.

The thing is that I have a week trying to find the way to get rid of the white space below my footer using the twenty sixteen theme. I found ironical the fact that something called "footer" is not really a footer. It's something that floats on a white space.

Do you have some suggestion about what can i do to place the footer at the bottom of the page and get rid of that white space?

[image]

I know that I can just make this:

```
.site-footer {
    padding: 0 7.6923% 1.75em;
    /* visibility: hidden; */
    height: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

But if I make this, then there is no a margin between my content and my footer:

[image]

**Edit**

I found that the position of my elements in the footer depends of the height of the content of my page. Now I'm looking for a way to stablish that the content of my page should occupy the 100% of the height but I can not find where. Do you have some suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you are hoping to achieve is to place the footer (the "Garrah Morris" signature) on the bottom of the browser window, when the content is less than 100% of the screen height.

One way to surely achieve this is by simply setting the footer containing div to `position:absolute;bottom:0;`. (Though it will cause overlapping issues when the content above it is over a certain height.)

Comment: Hello Django thank you for your answer. Yes that's the problem it works but it depends of the height of my content